# Symfony 3 - Unable to load the translations "messages" file

Tags: php, xml, symfony, twig, translation

I'm new in Symfony 3 and I hope you can help me.

I want to use the translation component in my project, I followed this steps " https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation.html#configuration " but when I clear the cache with the CLI, I have this error and the translations don't work:

```
>php bin/console cache:clear

// Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true


In XliffFileLoader.php line 56:

  Unable to load "C:\wamp64\www\MyWebSite/translations\messages.en_US.xlf": [ERROR 64] XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document (in n/a - line 2, column 6)


In XmlUtils.php line 62:

  [ERROR 64] XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document (in n/a - line 2, column 6)
```

These are my files:

- app/config/config.yml

  ```
  parameters:
      locale: en

  framework:
      #esi: ~
      translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
  ```
- translations\messages.fr_FR.xlf

  ```
  <!-- messages.fr.xlf -->
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
      <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
          <body>
              <trans-unit id="symfony_is_great">
                  <source>Symfony is great</source>
                  <target>J'aime Symfony</target>
              </trans-unit>
          </body>
      </file>
  </xliff>
  ```
- I use the tanslation in Twig file

  ```
  {% trans %} Symfony is great { endtrans %}
  ```

I hope you can help me !!

Comment: do you have `messages.en_US.xlf` file?

Comment: The `<?xml...?>` part should be in the first line, not the second. Switch it with your comment.

Comment: @PavelAlazankin I created the file `messages.en_US.xlf` and I still have the probleme

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479533/problem-xml-declaration-allowed-only-at-the-start-of-the-document @Maerlyn is right. as I can see, you just copied your code from symfony documentation. First line in their code samples are often used to point which file's code is provided, and should not be used in your code

Comment: @Maerlyn I did what you said and I don't have the errors anymore, but the translation doesn't work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What did you try and what was the expected result?

Comment: @Maerlyn can you wrote your answer in the answer place, because when I did what you said, the error that I has in the CLI has gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML parser is shouting at you because the document declaration needs to be on the first line. So switch these two lines and that error should disappear:

```
<!-- messages.fr.xlf -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

The translation may not be working because you have spaces around your string in the template, and not in the xml file:

```
<source>Symfony is great</source>
{% trans %} Symfony is great { endtrans %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... the translation now work when I began the translation file with `<?xml version="1.0"?>` as you said and I rename it `messages.fr.xlf` instead of `messages.fr_FR.xlf`